# What does navigationType : "reload" mean in Web Vitals INP report?

Tags: core-web-vitals, web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

I am using the [official](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-vitals/ahfhijdlegdabablpippeagghigmibma?hl=en) Web Vitals Chrome Extension. And I'm tracking the INP metrics for my web page. And saw this:

[image]

What does this mean? Is there any place to view the whole documents about the console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation type is determined by the [Navigation Timing API](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/#sec-performance-navigation-types).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type) also has a good explanation of the values:

> `"reload"`
>
> Navigation is through the browser's reload operation, `location.reload()` or a Refresh pragma directive like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">`.

The Web Vitals extension is based on the web-vitals.js library, whose [README](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals#metric) documents the entire object you see in the console.